# How to fix: Empty IP Address for nginx-ingress on digital-ocean

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

In my k8s cluster the ingress does not work on the k8s cluster of digital ocean. I don't get an external ip and so it is not available. Locally there seems to be no problem.

I already searched a lot and tried some tutorials, f.e. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes.
But it seems that it is an older version and the solution (and even the links) does not work anymore.

The nginx-ingress should call the service of a website backend which is on port 8080.

I stripped down my ingress code to the following one:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: website
          servicePort: 8080
```

With `kubectl get ing` I see the ingress, but it has no address. It looks like this

```
NAME           HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
test-ingress   *                 80      50s
```

Can anyone help me out and tell me what I have to do to get my k8s cluster running?

Thanks
peter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, if you are using Nginx Ingress Controller, you don't need to see ingress address.

When you install [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) to your k8s cluster, it creates Load Balancer to handle all incoming requests. Make sure that below part completed as explained in **Step 2** of [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes) you posted and you are able to see LoadBalancer External ip address.

```
$ kubectl get svc --namespace=ingress-nginx
```

You should see an external IP address, corresponding to the IP address of the DigitalOcean Load Balancer:

```
Output
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx   LoadBalancer   10.245.247.67   203.0.113.0   80:32486/TCP,443:32096/TCP   20h
```

In above case, after deploying your ingress resource, if you hit `http://203.0.113.0` you will get your `website:8080` backend service.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks. I didn't know that I have to setup the nginx-ingress service and controller by myself. After I did this, it worked. Not everything worked but this issue was fixed.

Comment: This helps a lot. But What if we have only CLUSTER-IP and not EXTERNAL-IP  as it's a local deployment